# OpenCV imshow does not work in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I am trying to run `cv2.imshow(...)` from a docker container to show the window on the host machine, and keep getting the following error:

```
[ERROR:0@0.195] global /opt/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (597) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) /opt/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): /src/test/output/test_april_output.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'


The program 'python' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 201 error_code 10 request_code 130 minor_code 1)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
ERROR: 1
non-network local connections being removed from access control list
```

I run the container through `run.sh`, and this setup works when you use OpenCV python pip package. I switched the Dockerfile to compiling from the source repo, and now I am getting GDK errors.

`run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
export XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth

xhost +local:docker
touch $XAUTH
xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
docker-compose build aerial_viewer
docker-compose run aerial_viewer
xhost -local:docker
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.8-slim
 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ 
    wget \
    g++ \
    bzip2 \
    build-essential \ 
    cmake \ 
    git \
    graphviz \
    unzip \ 
    pkg-config \
    protobuf-compiler \
    python-dev \ 
    python-opencv \ 
    libopencv-dev \ 
    libjpeg-dev \ 
    libpng-dev \
    libhdf5-dev \ 
    libtiff-dev \ 
    libgl1-mesa-glx \ 
    libgtk2.0-dev \ 
    python-pycurl \ 
    libatlas-base-dev \
    gfortran \
    webp \
    libcanberra-gtk-module \
    libcanberra-gtk3-module \
    openmpi-bin \
    qt5-default \
    libvtk6-dev \ 
    zlib1g-dev \
    libprotobuf-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN python3 -m pip install numpy==1.20.1

WORKDIR $HOME/src/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

ENV OPENCV_VERSION="4.5.5"

RUN wget -q https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv.zip \
    && wget -q --no-check-certificate https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv_contrib.zip \
    && unzip -qq opencv.zip -d /opt && rm -rf opencv.zip \
    && unzip -qq opencv_contrib.zip -d /opt && rm -rf opencv_contrib.zip \
    && cmake \
        -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}/modules \
        -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
        -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
        -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF \
        -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON \
        -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
        -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D BUILD_TBB=ON \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -D WITH_EIGEN=OFF \
        -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
        -D WITH_V4L=ON \
        -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
        -D WITH_VTK=OFF \
        -D WITH_GTK=ON \
        -D WITH_QT=OFF \
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ \
        -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && rm -rf /opt/build/* \
    && rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}

RUN git clone https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag.git --branch v3.1.7 && \
     cd apriltag && cmake . && make install && cd ../ && rm -rf apriltag

RUN (apt-get autoremove -y; \
     apt-get autoclean -y)  
     
COPY requirements.txt $HOME/src/

RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . $HOME/src/

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "aerial_viewer.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
aerial_viewer:
    image: star_aerial_viewer:latest
    build:
      context: aerial_viewer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
      - XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH
      - XSOCK=$XSOCK
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - $XSOCK:$XSOCK
      - $XAUTH:$XAUTH
```

Comment: Are you logging in as root?  Because you're telling it to use `/root/.Xauthority`.

Comment: Sorry that was just a edit for testing. Changed it back to what it should be. Same output either way with or without using `sudo ./run.sh`

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? @DaniyalManiar